# Cannot load xsl file

Tags: java, tomcat, xslt-1.0

I need to do a transformation in my java application. I am have trouble loading the the `xsl` file. I'm using tomcat, the path location is:

C:/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/config/myfile.xsl

if I use the full path the file loads but if I use `/config/myfile.xsl` I get a FileNotFoundException:

```
StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource("/config/myfile.xsl");
```

Comment: This spreadsheet is a resource of your webapp? If so, you should not try to read it as a file. Instead read it as a resource.

Comment: In Unix pathnames, a leading slash has a special meaning.

Comment: @Raedwald it is an `xsl` file not an excel file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ServletContext.getResource` to resolve paths relative to the webapp, e.g.

```
StreamSource xslt = new StreamSource(ctx.getResource(
    "/WEB-INF/classes/config/myfile.xsl").toString());
```

Alternatively you can use `getResourceAsStream` and create the StreamSource from an input stream instead of a URL, but if you do that then relative URLs inside your stylesheet won't resolve, so you can't use the `document` function with a relative URI in your XSLT.

Comment: Thanks, where doesn `ctx` come from?